# How to allow access only to specific routes

Tags: authentication, backbone.js, routes, restriction

I have defined a set of routes using backbone

For instance:

```
Backbone.Routes.prefix = Onethingaday.Routers
Backbone.Routes.map

"!*splat":
  "HomeRouter" : "reroute"

"":
  "NavbarRouter"  : "index"
  "SidebarRouter" : "index"
  "HomeRouter"    : "index"

"all":
  "NavbarRouter"  : "index"
  "SidebarRouter" : "index"
  "HomeRouter"    : "all"

"news":
  "NavbarRouter"        : "index"
  "SidebarRouter"       : "index"
  "NotificationsRouter" : "index"

"popular/threads":
  "NavbarRouter"   : "index"
  "SidebarRouter"  : "index"
  "DiscoverRouter" : "popularThreads"
```

Now, I want to restrict access to certain routes i.e. only able to access 'all' and 'news' routes if the user 'isLoginedIn'. How can I do a check here? Do can I check and compare and redirect the user to a separate login page if the user tries to access the 'all' and 'news' page for example

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you store the state of your current user, be it a `SessionController` or a `CurrentUser` model, you can always expose a method along the lines of `currentUser.isLoggedIn()`.

I am not entirely sure about your mapping, as Backbone only exposes a single-depth hashmap for routes (are you using something else do define your routes?)

In one of my Backbone apps I have code that's along the following lines:

```
home: function homeFn()
{
    if (this.app.currentUser.isAnonymous())
    {
        this.app.page('index');
    }
    else
    {
        this.app.page('dashboard');
    }
}
```

which gives you direct control within the route mapping. If you don't like this, you can always extend the Backbone.Router object to have before/after filters. At the time of writing, [this plugin](https://github.com/angelo0000/backbone_filters) is one I've used before and helped me out nicely doing exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes I do already have a method to know whether the user is logged in, so I can check isLoggedIn for the user. What I wasn't sure about was how I can differentiate the routes for a 'logined' user vs a 'non-logined' user. For example for the 'news' route, a loggedin user should be able to access w/o problems but for a non-logined user, I want to re-direct him to a separate login page. Basically I am intending to have some different actions for the diff routes if the user is not logged in e.g. news -> Go to login page, popular - allow access etc